# Anaconda prompt giving an error on opening

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I tried to install anaconda 2.7 on my new computer(running win10), but failed. 
I had it installed on my old laptop (running win7), and I was using spyder happily. Now after the install, the Navigator refuses to open, and the anaconda prompt gives an error first hand when opening.

The error i am receiving:

---

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 12, in 
    sys.exit(main())

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 145, in main
    init_loggers()

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 56, in init_loggers
    from ..gateways.logging import initialize_logging, set_verbosity

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\logging.py", line 14, in 
    from ..common.io import attach_stderr_handler

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 580, in 
    class time_recorder(ContextDecorator):  # pragma: no cover

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 581, in time_recorder
    record_file = get_instrumentation_record_file()

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 577, in get_instrumentation_record_file
    return expand(os.environ.get("CONDA_INSTRUMENTATION_RECORD_FILE", default_record_file))

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\common\path.py", line 49, in expand
    return abspath(expanduser(expandvars(path))
    enter code here

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\ntpath.py", line 311, in expanduser
    return userhome + path[i:]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 13: invalid continuation byte

---

I tried reinstalling anaconda completely, tried both 64 and 32 bit versions, tried miniconda, same error all the time. 
Would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be related to **non-utf-8** characters in your home directory.

See a similar issues for 'ascii' codec:

https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1631

https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1180

If you need to use Python 2 it is suggested to use Anaconda3 and create a Python 2 environment from that.